# git rebase doesnt show commits

Tags: git, github

I cloned a github repo after forking it and did

```
git remote add upstream (url)
git checkout --track origin/master
git checkout develop
git checkout -b new_feature_name
```

then some changes and

```
git commit
git fetch upstream
git checkout develop
git rebase upstream/develop
git checkout new_feature_name
git rebase develop
git push
```

git says everything is upto date(why!!)
but i am not seeing changes on github??whats wrong with the workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your workflow is slightly inconsistent, so I can't say, why git sees no changes.

But I would push new branches always like this

```
git push origin develop:develop
git push origin new_feature_name:new_feature_name
```